# Which is correct with the subject "bad spelling and grammar"? IS/ARE turn-offs/a turn-off

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

> 1. Bad spelling and grammar is a major turn-off.
> 2. Bad spelling and grammar are a major turn-off.
> 3. Bad spelling and grammar are major turn-offs.

Which of the sentences above is correct?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether you take a descriptive or prescriptive view of grammar. A descriptive grammarian would likely say all three are acceptable because you will hear all three.

A prescriptive grammarian like me says that # 2 is bad grammar. There is no question that # 3 is perfectly grammatical: subject, verb, and copula are all plural. The one that raises a grammatical question is # 1.

At least in U.S. English, certain phrases such as **bacon and eggs** are treated in some contexts as a singular concept despite the plural form. Someone may say **Bacon and eggs is my favorite breakfast** meaning that
**the combination of bacon and eggs is what I like best for breakfast.** In that example, it is the combination of foods that is being referenced rather than the individual components. Obviously, **bad spelling and grammar** can also be used as a combined concept because they do, in empirical fact, often appear together. So # 1 is good grammar.

Nevertheless, I prefer # 3 because I am not sure that **bad spelling and grammar** is as generally recognized as a single thing as is **bacon and eggs.**

Comment: It's incorrect to say that descriptive grammarians deem something grammatical because "you will hear it". You can hear children or English learners say, for example, *I goed home.* yet I don't think any serious expert would deem that grammatical. A good explanation of prescriptivism vs descriptivism can be found in Chapter 1 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,* available here: http://www.cambridge.org/features/linguistics/cgel/sample.htm Your designation of #2 as *bad* merely reflects your personal taste.

Comment: According to your reasoning, *They are a couple* is "bad grammar". Would you agree?